# Can I omit the repeated 'of which'?

Tags: relative-pronouns, ellipsis

given the following sentence

> I have a snake of which the head is white and (of which) the tail is black.

In this expression, can I omit the second (of which)?
Or shouldn't I omit it?

Comment: I think omitting the second "of which" would improve the sentence.  Other formulations seem even better.  Consider the version using "with" in the answer from BladorthinTheGrey, and consider "I have a snake whose head is white and whose tail is black."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: **yes**, you could omit the second *of which* and get away with it.

However, this sentence is not very good to start off with; usually, when describing attributes of an object, you use adjectives or the preposition *with*.

For instance:

> I have a sneak *with* a white head  and a black tail.

Or

> I have a white-headed and black-tailed sneak.

The first alternative—using *with*—is more idiomatic.

Comment: Alternatively, one might use "I have a snake whose head is white and (whose) tail is black" or a combination like "I have a white-headed snake whose tail is black."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given that the conjunction "and" can be taken to subject the next phrase to the first "of which." And if the parentheses are original, they themselves are a clue because all that go between parentheses can always be dropped without harming the structure of a sentence (even though harming its meaning, as just in this parenthesized phrase!;).